# Blender 2.80: Newly created object appears in unused/invisible collection - how to avoid?

Tags: mesh, objects

I am using Blender 2.80 on Linux.

When I create an object (Add->Mesh->...) it will be put into an
collection, which is set "invisible" (not used).

How can I avoid this?
How can I predetermine where new object get inserted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the active group in **outliner**:

[image]

The **white gray circle** in the *collection icon* indicate that is the active collection now, all new object will link to there.

You can manually click on other Collection (include scene collection) to change the active collection in order to insert any thing in to desired group.